# How to Fetch the disk detail in linux?

Tags: awk

I want to fetch the disk detail as below :-

```
disk Name : Total:Used:Free
```

i have fetched the below one via : `pvs  |awk '{print $1, "" $5, "" $6}'`

```
PV PSize PFree
/dev/sda5 2.00g 1020.00m
/dev/sda6 3.00g 3.00g
/dev/sda7 4.00g 4.00g
```

Now i want one column after PFree which will show Used disk space       (Psize - PFree ) ,please anyone do let me know how to fetch used disk space via script

Comment: why not use `df` command?

Comment: that will be more complicated , of you know please tell me the script code

Comment: Actually want the details of each disk on the system i want the output like :-   Disk Name : Total_Size::Used_Size::Free_Size

Comment: Welcome to U&L , you can [edit here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/398012/edit)

Comment: @Sunita, the only nuance that `df` will *report file system disk space usage*, (could show `Filesystem      Size Avail  Used`)

Answer (score 1):

This command will give you the disk space.

```
df -h -x tmpfs | egrep -v '^udev'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 pvs  --units=m | awk '{Used=($5-$6)m;print $1, "" $5, "" $6,Used"m"}' | sed -e 's/0m$/PUsed/1g' | column -t
```

- `--units=m` to print size in megabits
- `Used=($5-$6)` to get different between PSize and PFree.
- `'s/0m$/PUsed/1g'` to have PUsed header
- `column -t` to format the output